# Apply CSS to specific div on button click

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to implemented a functionality where a div gets highlighted in some color and the mouse pointer turns to hand. I am able to do this by applying a class

```css
.changePointer:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(231, 222, 222);
}
```

and it works fine.

But I want to make this happen only on a button click. So on a button click, if I hover over a div, its gets highlighted and gets hand cursor. I am using Angular 7. I tried using `[ngClass]="{'someClass': highlightText}"` and change the `highlightText` `boolean` to `true` but that did not help. Any suggestions?

Comment: you mean, you click a button and hover over a div *at the same time*?

Comment: anyway, the solution'd be just add the class `.changePointer` to the element when you want.

Comment: No. I click I button then I hover any of the multiple divs that are available, that specific div gets highlighted

Answer (score 4):

Use class as follows, (`active` is class name here).

```html
<div [class.active]="condition"></div>
```

In `css` add `:hover` to `active` class,

```css
.active:hover {
  background-color: red;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-qcdx3d?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Comment: Thanks for you help but I think this applies the class on click. I want to add the class on hover. So on click the mouose changes to hand and applies the color to the div whose text is hovered.

Comment: Do you mean to say that `:hover` behavior should be added after button click only?

Comment: Yes, :hover behavior should be added after button click only.

Comment: Updated demo. `:hover` will be added after click.

Answer (score 3):

you can use [Renderer2](https://angular.io/api/core/Renderer2) to manipulate the element's css.

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="container__item" *ngFor="let div of [1,2,3]" (click)="onClick($event)">
    </div>
</div>
```

Component:

```
  import { Component, Renderer2 } from '@angular/core';


  constructor(private rndr2: Renderer2) {}

  onClick(ev) {
    this.rndr2.addClass(ev.target, 'changePointer')
  }
```

DEMO:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gaa6zi?file=src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: Thanks Stavm but the pointer is not changing to hand on click of the button. Like I mentioned, on click the mouse changes to hand and applies the color to the div whose text is hovered.

Comment: @YogeshMali you can add a boolean flag, updated the demo.

Comment: The hand icon is not coming on hover but I made some changes and got it to work. Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You can use event listener to do this in JavaScript.

```
button.addEventListner('click', (e) => {
    div.style.backgroundColor = 'rgb(231, 222, 222)';
    div.style.cursor = 'pointer';
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Just add the class `.changePointer` to the element only when you want

```js
function toggleTargets(){
  //I use dataset attribute, but you can select targets anyway you want
  let targets = document.querySelectorAll('[data-type=A]')
  targets.forEach(elem=>elem.classList.toggle('changePointer'))
}
```

```css
.changePointer:hover {
    cursor: pointer;
    background-color: rgb(231, 222, 222);
}

div{border:1px solid black; margin:5px;}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="toggleTargets()">CLICK</button>

<div data-type=A>A</div>
<div data-type=B>B</div>
<div data-type=C>C</div>
<div data-type=A>D</div>
<div data-type=B>E</div>
<div data-type=C>F</div>
<div data-type=A>G</div>
<div data-type=B>H</div>
<div data-type=C>I</div>
```